# What is a good or best in your opinion way to do OOP in C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have been working on coming up with the best wy to put the classes for the best OOP.  Sometimes I wonder if I am trying to over kill the thought process.

I am thinking now to have as an examples the Categories Object

Files

1. Cateogories.cs - Object File
2. CateogoriesDAL.cs - Data Access Layer
3. CateogoriesBLL.cs - Business Logic Layer
4. CateogoriesWS.cs - Web Service

When you call form any application local or external you would call the web service and it would get what you need.

Examples:
You would create a Categories Object so you could pass it to the Web Service Layer when you wanted to Save (Insert or Update) a Category.  All of the business rules would be in the Business Logic Layer.

How do you implement the OOP?

Comment: Okay I have been talking at work with someone they don't like NHibernate is this just due to someone not liking to loose control or is this a common feeling?

Comment: Should the properites for the Class to be only in the Object file?
I would think you would create the CategoriesBLL and in there is would create the Object and then you would set the object values?  I am getting confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into using an Object/Relational-Mapper (ORM) such as [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) to simplify things. You could then use a simple [domain driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) approach with Repositories, Services etc.

EDIT: The repositories are responsible for the actual interaction with the data layer; Get/Save entities. Then you could use Domain Services for actual "business logic".